# Prolog exercise with factorisation

Tags: prolog, prime-factoring

I am currently studying Artificial Intelligence in the Netherlands. We've had some introductions about Prolog which were very simple and understandable, but the exercises we have to do are a little more difficult.

An exercise which I don't fully understand is exercise 5.6. Could somebody give me a hint/explanation on how to solve this exercise, with eventually a working program?

Thank you very much!

> Exercise  5.6.
>   Write  a  predicate
>   `factor/2`
>   to  compute  the  prime  factorisation  of  a
>   given integer > 2. (Equal or more than 2).
>
> Use the same notation as in the following examples:
>
> ```
> ?- factor(30, X).
> X = [2, 3, 5]
> Yes
>
> ?- factor(300, X).
> X = [2^2, 3, 5^2]
> Yes
>
> ?- factor(1024, X).
> X = [2^10]
> Yes
>
> ?- factor(17, X).
> X = [17]
> Yes
> ```
>
> Use your program to compute the prime factorisations of `7777777` and
>   `12345654321`.

What I’ve tried is,
This basecase:

```
factor(_, 0, []).
```

(which probably isn’t perfect)

And

```
factor(N, Result):-
    factor(N, N2, X, Result).
factor(N, N3, X, Result):-
    N2 is N3 - 1.
    N mod N2 is X
```

Comment: This is not the way StackOverflow works: this is not a homework dumping service. You should specify what you tried, and what did not work (and what you think is wrong with it).

Answer (score 1):

So you want it to hold that

```erlang
factor(30, [2, 3, 5]).
factor(300, [2^2, 3, 5^2]).
factor(1024, [2^10]).
factor(17, [17]).
```

Let's first see about

```erlang
3 ?- write_canonical( factor(300, [2^2, 3, 5^2]) ).
factor(300,[^(2,2),3,^(5,2)])
true.
```

Obviously we want

```erlang
factor(10, [2, 5]).
```

and we know that `30 * 10 == 300`, thus we have

```erlang
factor(30, [2, 3, 5]).
factor(10, [2, 5]).
factor(300, [2^2, 3, 5^2]).
```

So let's first solve for the simpler

```erlang
factor(30, [2, 3, 5]).
factor(10, [2, 5]).             %  10 ==  2*5
factor(300, [2, 2, 3, 5, 5]).   % 300 == 10*300
```

and so it must also hold that

```erlang
factor(150, [2, 3, 5, 5]).      % 300 == 2 *150
factor(75, [3, 5, 5]).          % 150 == 2 *75
factor(25, [5, 5]).             %  75 == 3 *25
factor(5, [5]).                 %  25 == 5 *5
```

Thus we already see that

```erlang
factor( N, [F | FS]) :- 
    between(2,N,F),
    ( divides(F, N) -> M is N div F, 
                       factor(.........)  ).   % recursion!
```

And all that's left for you to do is to fill in the missing pieces.

Recursion!

Comment: Oh the recursion has something to do with te Tail of the clause, right? In this case this is named FS. And isn’t there a basecase for when the list is empty?

Comment: you need to complete the definitions, yes. recursion means, "do the same to solve a smaller problem". it helps; it frees us from having to see the problem through to the end -- this will happen on its own. we just focus on the current situation: 300 = 2*150; whatever the factors of 150 are, the factors of 300 have one more number in front of them (and that number is ___).

Comment: Well, you have to create a 'loop' to make this a recursion, so I was guessing that the missing factor had to be factor(M, FS) or factor(FS, M)...

Comment: And will prolog automatically use '^' in the answers?

Comment: yes to the (M, FS), and no to the (FS, M): it should be *the same as* the main call, and *it* has the *number*, N, as the first argument. As for the `^`s, no, it won't. But let's focus first on solving it in principle, and *then* on massaging the output into some specific form. *Stepwise* development... (when you get to that point, please ask a *new* question, if you need to). -- re "loop", you're thinking in operational terms still. Instead, recursion is a declarative tool: we let it "do the same" to solve a similar, yet smaller, problem.